# PHP using array as function

Tags: php

I have created two code snippets at 
http://codepad.viper-7.com/o5MxgF
and http://codepad.viper-7.com/qUpTag

In the second snippet, I was trying to use array as a call back because I found at 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
that

> Note: Both square brackets and curly braces can be used
>   interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and
>   $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).

So, I thought I could use array as a function so that I don't need the declare

```
$get_new_key = function ($k) use($fa) {
  return $fa[$k];
};
```

But as you can see, I was getting a

> : array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array
>   member is not a valid class name or object in /code/qUpTag on line 8

error.

Are there anything to make array a callable without creating a companion function to access its values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Having a callable array doesn't mean that it returns the values of the array. Instead, it's an array that points to a method on either a class or object.

For instance, `array('MyClass', 'my_method')` is a callable for the static method `my_method` on `MyClass` and `array($object, 'method')` is a callable for the instance method `method` on the object in `$object`.

You can read more about the callable type in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)